# Laravel Query Builder Unions: Add 'table name' column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, union, laravel-query-builder

There are 3 different database tables `articles`, `reviews`, `posts` and all of them have these columns: `'id', 'title', 'user_id', 'created_at', 'body'`.

I am using Laravel 5.6 and [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) package, so I need to "union" these three tables and put that into jQuery DataTables. 
To do that I'm using Laravel's  `union` query builder method:

```
    $fields = [
        'id',
        'title',
        'user_id', 
        'created_at',
        'body'
    ];

    $articles = DB::table('articles')->select($fields);
    $reviews = DB::table('reviews')->select($fields);
    $posts = DB::table('posts')->select($fields);

    $union = $articles->union($reviews)->union($posts)->get();

    dd($union);
```

... and this works fine, the result looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+
| id |    title    | user_id | created_at | body |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+
|  1 | Some title  |       1 | ...        | ...  |
|  1 | Lorem ipsum |       2 | ...        | ...  |
|  1 | Test        |       1 | ...        | ...  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+
```

The problem is that I need to know from which table is each record (row). 
Is it possible to add a custom column (for example "source") which would contain the DB table name? (using Query Builder)

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+----------+
| id |    title    | user_id | created_at | body |  source  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+----------+
|  1 | Some title  |       1 | ...        | ...  | articles |
|  1 | Lorem ipsum |       2 | ...        | ...  | reviews  |
|  1 | Test        |       1 | ...        | ...  | posts    |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `DB::raw` custom field to your `fields` array within `select` like:

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')->select(array_merge($fields, [DB::raw('"articles" as source')]));
$reviews = DB::table('reviews')->select(array_merge($fields, [DB::raw('"reviews" as source')]));
$posts = DB::table('posts')->select(array_merge($fields, [DB::raw('"posts" as source')]));
```

this should add `source` field to your result set

Answer (score 1):

There's no function to return the table that's the source of a row. It would have to return a list if you had a JOIN for example, and it would be further complicated by derived table subqueries and so on.

The way to do this in a UNION is to add a custom column to each query in the UNION with a string constant that you use to name the table.

```
SELECT 'articles' as table_name, id, title, user_id, created_at, body
FROM articles
UNION
SELECT 'reviews', id, title, user_id, created_at, body
FROM reviews
UNION
SELECT 'posts', id, title, user_id, created_at, body
FROM posts
```

(You only need to define the column alias in the first query, it will apply to all rows returned by the UNION.)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects shows an example of a custom column in the select-list

So you should be able to just define the extra column in your fields:

```
$common_fields = [
    'id',
    'title',
    'user_id', 
    'created_at',
    'body'
];

$fields = array_merge(["articles as table_name"], $common_fields)
$articles = DB::table('articles')->select($fields);

$fields = array_merge(["reviews"], $common_fields)
$reviews = DB::table('reviews')->select($fields);

$fields = array_merge(["posts"], $common_fields)
$posts = DB::table('posts')->select($fields);
```

I have not tested the above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, your answer is correct but it didn't work (I was getting `Column not found...` error)... you just needed to use `DB::raw` as @Seva Kalashnikov did in his answer. Again, thank you very much!